# Journald to rsyslog forwarding confusion

Tags: debian, logs, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I do not really understand the forwarding from Journald to Rsyslog.

Basically I understood it in the way that the 'pipeline' is built up as follows:

> Kernel logs through printk() → /proc/kmesg ← rsyslog → writes to log file according to rules in rsyslog.conf
>
> Userspace logs → /dev/log ← rsyslog → writes to log file according to rules in rsyslog.conf

This results in the various log files, such as /var/log/syslog etc.

As in the rsyslog.conf snippet, messages from the facility 'user' are also written to syslog and are therefore stored twice, right?

```
#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none -/var/log/syslog
#cron.* /var/log/cron.log
daemon.* -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.* -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.* -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.* -/var/log/mail.log
user.* -/var/log/user.log
```

So far so clear, if I've got it right.

However, /dev/log seems to be linked to

```
$ ls -lah /dev/log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Apr 15 16:30 /dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

Why is that?

To get back to my real question. Where does Journald get the logs? I only know systemd-cat. Or also from /dev/log // /run/systemd/journal/dev-log?

Journald forwards the logs to syslog (standard in Debian according to https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-de/journald.conf.5.de.html). Shouldn't every message be duplicated in syslog?

To close the loop, I am at this point because I am planning a log management environment and am faced with the question of where to get my logs from.

I thank you in advance and hope that you can help me.

Comment: This is pretty much https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205883/5132 again, differing only in incidentals, with a bit of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332315/5132 thrown in.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have already read the first one and the second one has given me some additional clarity, but unfortunately not everything.

If both rsyslog and journald read from /dev/log (or the link and socket provided for syslog) and journald on Debian has ForwardToSyslog enabled by default, why don't all messages duplicate?

Comment: That's already covered in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand logging in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205883/understand-logging-in-linux)

Comment: @AdminBee your link is essentially the same as JdeBP's (Theirs just points to an answer of the same question, while yours points to the question)

Comment: @Wimateeka That is true. My comment was auto-generated while reviewing this question, because I flagged it as possible duplicate to one in the link.